# Building a LIRC configuration from RemoteMaster project files

Tags: gpio, pi-2, lirc

I'd like to use an RPi to send IR codes to an old Balboa hot tub that doesn't support a Wifi module. I've bought the original IR receiver that plugs into the hot tub's motherboard. However, I don't want to buy the Dolphin 2 remote control, which is very expensive, because I don't want to use it anyway. My goal is to send some command to the hot tub through Internet. I connected an IR transmitter module to the RPi running BullSeye OS. I have RemoteMaster configuration files (with map and rdf extensions). Does anyone know how to create a LIRC configuration from such a source ? Or if someone has this Dolphin 2 remote control, could they please create a mapping file for me in LIRC ? Many thanks in advance. Diwi.

Comment: May be simpler to buy a programmable remote.  E.g. something like the urc-1280